# ld : _start not found defaulting to

Tags: c, gcc, ld

Hi I made a simple hello world C program and I am compiling it like this :

`gcc -c hello.c`
`ld hello.o -lc -o out`

I get a warning from ld : `ld : _start not found defaulting to ....`

I do an `objdump -D hello.o` and I cannot find the `_start` routine in the output.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: probably you're missing main(); or have an invalid declaration of main

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are invoking `ld` directly?

Comment: gcc `hello.c` works fine and I am not missing main()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `crt*` stuff which you will see if you link with `gcc -v`: `crt1.o`, `crtend.o`, `crtn.o`. Look at how `gcc` invokes `collect2` (it's visible with `gcc -v`) and use the same options for `ld`.

`main` function is not the executable entry point: some initialization for standard library is done before `main` (because it's either impossible or illogical to do otherwise). Real entry point, which is `_start` by default, is in `crt1.o` which is always linked into your executable.

Comment: how do I pass crtn.o to `ld`.Or Is it what I need to do ?

Comment: `ld -o out -L/lib/crt0.o cprog.o -lc`. Even this doesn't work.

Comment: `crt0.o` (or crt1 or whatever you have, may be target-dependent) is an object, not a library. You pass it exactly as `cprog.o`, without `-L`.

Comment: `ld -o out /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o cprog.o -lc` now its telling me undefined reference to _init

Comment: yep, you're making progress. Add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o` (or *finally* take a *look* at `gcc -v` output which tells you the same thing).

Comment: ok so i linked with crti crtn and crt1 . Now I dont get any warnings but my out is not getting executed by the bash. : `./out no such file or directory`. I am using an env variable `$MYVAR = /usr/lib/..../crt*`.

Comment: Add `-dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, and ensure that you link `crt1.o` and `crti.o` at the beginning, then your object file, then `crtn.o` (from the same directory as other `crt*`). Or look at `gcc -v` *output*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23493/discussion-between-deepankar-bajpeyi-and-anton-kovalenko)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have a main function, also you can try

```
gcc -v hello.c -o hello
```

See if it compiles successfully.

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi the important part is `-v`: gcc shows you how it is linking (look at `collect2` invocation)

Comment: it is huge with a bunch of Env variables.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Angstrom Linux, gcc 4.3.3), it happened due me installing `libgcc-s-dev` instead of `libgcc-dev`. No binary on the system contained `_start` string, I checked that. Installing `libgcc-dev` helped.